# Running into "Py4JJavaError" while converting list to Dataframe using

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
         Summary: Running into "Py4JJavaError" while converting list to Dataframe using
```

Python, Jupyter notebook
                 Key: SPARK-24612
                 URL: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24612
             Project: Spark
          Issue Type: Question
          Components: PySpark
    Affects Versions: 2.3.1
         Environment: >python --version

Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.

> java -version

java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)

> jupyter --version

4.4.0

> conda -V

conda 4.5.4

spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7
            Reporter: A B

rdd=sc.parallelize([[1,"Alice",50],[2,"Bob",80]])

rdd.collect()
[[1,"Alice",50],[2,"Bob",80]]

However, when i run df=rdd.toDF()
i run into the following error: Any help resolving this error is greatly appreciated.

full link here http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-issues/201806.mbox/%3CJIRA.13167277.1529535154000.212161.1529535180018@Atlassian.JIRA%3E

Answer (score 0):

That's because you use inconsistent types:

- In the first row the last value is an `int`.
- In the second row the last values is a `str`.

Therefore types are incompatible with the inferred schema.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I made a correction: [[1, 'Alice', 50], [2, 'Bob', 80]]. The error still persists.